# PHP, al reloguear reenvia los datos

Tags: php, post, url, get

Tengo un formulario en PHP que pasa los datos por método POST a la misma página (ya que el action es el por defecto).

Cuando un usuario introduce mal un dato, por ejemplo, su contraseña, esto queda registrado en la base de datos, el problema está cuándo refresco la página (Recargar página actual control+r en firefox). (Que no F5, eso lo recarga de manera 'entera').

Bien, cuándo recargo la página de esa forma, los datos introducidos se vuelven a introducir.

Imagino que es porque en la url internamente esta pasando los datos tal que: `Página.php?User="Yoquesé"&password="Ejemplo"`

entonces al reloguear la página vuelve a mandar esos datos. ¿Cómo puedo limpiar esa 'url' una vez los datos han sido mandados?

Se me ocurre pasar los datos por variables y no por $_POST y una vez mandados dejar las variables vacias, pero ¿hay alguna otra alternativa?

Edito con el código, como comentasteis:

**Login.php** Con sus respectivos formularios, y demás.

```
  <?php

  include 'Sharkiquerys/SharkiQuerys.php';
  $Query = new SharkiQuerys();

  if(isset($_POST['user']) && strlen($_POST['user'])>0 &&
  isset($_POST['password']) && strlen($_POST['password'])>0){

    $Query->Iniciar_sesion($_POST['user'], $_POST['password']);
  }

  ?>
```

Y aqui estaría el método Iniciar sesión de la clase que me monté.

```
<?php
  /*________________________________________
        MÉTODO INICIAR SESIÓN
  ________________________________________*/
  public function Iniciar_sesion($usuario, $password){

    if(password_verify($password, $this->Consulta("SELECT PASSWORD FROM registro WHERE USER =:usuario", array(':usuario' => $usuario))->fetchColumn())){

      session_start();
      $_SESSION['user'] = $this->Consulta("SELECT USER FROM registro WHERE USER = :usuario", array(':usuario' => $usuario))->fetchColumn();

      # Si los datos introducidos son correctos.
      header('Location:Desafios.php');
      # Si la contraseña es incorrecta.
    }else{ $this->Alerta('Contraseña y/o usuario incorrecto.', 'red');}
  }
?>
```

Comment: podrias poner tu codigo de como realizas dicho proceso

Comment: Lo que necesitas hacer es un [POST/REDIRECT/GET (PRG)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Pon tu código para que sea mas facil darte una respuesta adecuada

Comment: Buenas! Acabo de actualizar la pregunta con el código que estoy usando, Gracias por vuestra respuesta! :)

Answer (score 0):

Parece que los valores de `$_POST` aún llevan los variables en este caso puedes devolver una matriz vacía.

```
public function Iniciar_sesion($usuario, $password){

 $query = $this->Consulta("SELECT PASSWORD FROM registro WHERE USER =:usuario", array(':usuario' => $usuario))->fetchColumn();
 if(password_verify($password, $query)){

   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user'] = $this->Consulta("SELECT USER FROM registro WHERE USER = :usuario", array(':usuario' => $usuario))->fetchColumn();

   # Si los datos introducidos son correctos.
   header('Location:Desafios.php');
   # Si la contraseña es incorrecta.
 }else{ 
   // Aqui tienes que devolver $_POST vacios $_POST[] = array();
   $usuario = "";
   $password = "";
   $_POST = array();

   $this->Alerta('Contraseña y/o usuario incorrecto.', 'red');
 }
}
```

No he probado este codigo